# Calculating Bank holidays between two given dates and showing difference in minutes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, c#-3.0, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to calculate the no of bank holidays in between two given dates for example 31/10/2019 10:00:00  and 01/11/2019 08:00:00 assuming 01/11/2019 is a bank holiday. I should get the bank holiday difference in minutes as 480 minutes in total. I am using the following code where if the one of given date falls on same date as bank holiday then my code is returning 1440 which is wrong, Can someone please suggest how to achieve this. Thanks

```
 DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(2019, 10, 31, 10, 0, 0);
DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1, 8, 0, 0);

public static int CountOfBusinessClosures(DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay, IOrganizationService service)
{
   // firstDay = firstDay.Date;
   // lastDay = lastDay.Date;

    var count = 0;         

    var businessClosuresdate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0);//GetBusinessClosureCalendarRules(service);

    // Count the number of bank holidays in between the given dates

    if (firstDay <= businessClosuresdate && businessClosuresdate <= lastDay)
    {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

OR

```
 public static double CountOfBusinessClosures2(DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay, IOrganizationService service)
    {
       var firstDay1 = firstDay.Date;
       var lastDay1 = lastDay.Date;

        var count = 0;            
        double t = 0;           

       // var businessClosures = GetBusinessClosureCalendarRules(service);

        // Count the number of bank holidays during the time interval
       // foreach (var closure in businessClosures)
       // {               
            var startDate = 01/11/2019 00:00:00 //(DateTime)closure["effectiveintervalstart"];
            var endDate = 02/11/2019 00:00:00 // (DateTime)closure["effectiveintervalend"];
            DateTime bh1 = startDate.Date;

            if (firstDay1 <= bh1 && bh1 <= lastDay1)
            {
                //  count++;
                if (firstDay.Date < startDate.Date && startDate.Date != endDate.Date)
                {
                    t += 1440; // 24h * 60 min
                }

                else
                {
                    double difference;
                    difference = (endDate - startDate).TotalMinutes;
                    difference = difference - (firstDay - startDate).TotalMinutes;
                    t += difference;
                }

            }
       // }
        return t;
    }

private static IEnumerable<Entity> GetBusinessClosureCalendarRules(IOrganizationService service)
    {

        // Get Organization Business Closure Calendar Id
        var organization = service.Retrieve("organization", _orgId, new ColumnSet("businessclosurecalendarid"));

        var query = new QueryExpression("calendar")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
        };

        // Add condition to get Get Calander where CalanderId is equal to Organization's businessclosurecalendarid
        query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("calendarid", ConditionOperator.Equal, organization["businessclosurecalendarid"].ToString()));

        // Get Calendar
        var businessClosureCalendar = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities[0];
        return businessClosureCalendar == null || businessClosureCalendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules") == null ? null : businessClosureCalendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules").Entities;
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing what is being returned from those functions, it's hard to tell. But you are obviously fulfilling that first if statement's conditions. Have you already breakpointed it in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi floating_camel, I am just retrieving the bank holidays using that function where assume 01/11/2019 full day as bank holiday. My expected result is 480 minutes because 24 hours minus 16 hours remaining is 8 hours so how I can calculate through code

Comment: If you are expecting to get 480 minutes from your date difference instead of 1440 it's probably because your start and end effective dates don't include time. The difference between one day and the next at the same time is 24hrs (1440 minutes), if you're expecting 8hrs (480 minutes) your dates (start and end) should probably be the same day but different times (open and close time) include the time for each.

Comment: Bellam, I understand now. But have you verified that you are entering the else statement or are you in fact entering the if statement and adding the 1440 there?

Comment: Hi Nick Henry, I agree with you that is where I am struggling a bit to include that in code. Could you please suggest how I can achieve it

Comment: All what I am trying to achieve is, I want to calculate the partial time difference in bank holidays...I am fine returning full day in between these given two dates.

Comment: Hi floating_camel, Yes I verified and it is going into if loop and adding 1440.

Comment: @Nick Henry, In the given example 01/11/2019 start time as 00:00:00 and end time as 02/11/2019 00:00:00. Where I need to calculate the difference

Comment: @Bellam I guess that's what I was referring to, the difference between these will always be one full day (1440 minutes). I'm not sure how/why you are expecting to only get a difference of 8 hrs here (480 minutes). I may be able to help if you can clarify why it should return this other value.

Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Henry, I need this code to be handling partial hours and full days difference because I am considering this total in my other calculations for working hours difference

Comment: I have simplified the code and shown above, which is returning no of bank holidays in between given two dates successfully but I need it to handle partial days also

Comment: @Bellam another thing I noticed is that you are using `.Date` a lot on your DateTime variables, this essentially throws the time away and just uses midnight (00) for the hour. This may be the root of the problem with your logic. I still don't fully understand which date is for what. If removing the `.Date` where appropriate doesn't help please list out what is: The range you are checking to contain holidays, the actual start and end DateTime (with time) of the sample holiday start and end. I think this will help with you getting an answer that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Bellam Try this and see if it suits your needs:

```
// Unit Test Class
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void C58840237T01()
    {
        DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(2019, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        double totalMinutesBusinessIsClosed = C58840237.MinutesBusinessIsClosed(firstDay, lastDay);
        Assert.IsTrue(totalMinutesBusinessIsClosed == 480);
    }
}


// Sample Class
public class C58840237
{
    public static double MinutesBusinessIsClosed(DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay)
    {
        double t = 0;

        // Holiday 01
        var h01Start = Convert.ToDateTime("11/01/2019 08:00:00");
        var h01End = Convert.ToDateTime("11/01/2019 16:00:00");

        // Holiday is in range
        if (firstDay <= h01Start && h01Start >= lastDay)
        {
            return (h01End - h01Start).TotalMinutes;
        }

        return t;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I realize our date time formats are different, but that's easily adjustable.